Proof that finite structure realizes all $n$-types.
I am trying to prove the following result but without much success, I hope you can help me here. The result I wish to prove is the following:
"Let $\underline{M}$ be a finite structure. For each $n\in \mathbb{N}$ and all $A\subseteq M$, every $n$-type is realized in $\underline{M}_A$" where by $\underline{M}_A$ i mean the structure $\underline{M}$ in the language expanded with a different constant symbol for each element of $A$.
Any help is very much appreciated :)

What definition of type are you using? Do you know the result that any type is realized in an elementary extension? (And then… what are the elementary extensions of finite structure?)

in the situation I described for me an n-type over $A$ in $\underline{M}$ is a set $p(x_1,\dots,x_n)$ of formulas with parameters from $A$ such that $p(x_1,\dots,x_n)$ is finitely satisfiable in $\underline{M}_A$. As for the result you mentioned, I never heard of it.

here is one approach. let $p(x_1,\dots,x_n)$ be an $n$-type over $A\subseteq M$. for each finite $\Delta\subseteq p$, let $k_\Delta$ be the number of $n$-tuples from $\underline{M}A$ that satisfy every formula in $\Delta$. note that $k\Delta\leqslant |M|^n$ for all $\Delta$; pick a finite subset $\Delta\subseteq p$ with $k_\Delta$ minimal possible. since $p$ is a type and $\Delta$ is finite, $1\leqslant k_\Delta$, and so there is $\bar{b}\in M^n$ satisfying every formula in $\Delta$; now show that $\bar{b}$ realizes $p$

I thought about this but unfortunately I can't proceed from where you suggested :/

@WiggedFern936 If $b$ didn't realize $p,$ i.e. $\lnot\varphi(b)$ held for some $\varphi\in p$, then $\Delta\cup{\varphi}$ would need to have fewer than $k_{\Delta}$ realizations.

Claim: $p(x)$ is a type over $A\subseteq M$ (i.e. finitely satisfiable in $\mathcal{M}$) if and only if $p(x)$ is realized in an elementary extension of $\mathcal{M}$.
Proof: Let $\mathcal{M}$ be a finite structure, $A\subseteq\mathcal{M}$, and $p(x)$ be a type over $A$. By the definition of type, $p(x)$ is finitely satisfiable in $\mathcal{M}$, so $\text{Th}_M(\mathcal{M})\cup p(c)$ is finitely satisfiable, where $\text{Th}_M(\mathcal{M}):=\text{Th}(\mathcal{M})\cup\{\varphi(c_{a_1},\cdots,c_{a_n})\,|\,\mathcal{M}\models\varphi(a_1,\cdots,a_n)\}$ and $c$ is a constant symbol. By the compactness theorem, there is an elementary extension $\mathcal{N}$ of $\mathcal{M}$ realizing $p(x)$. Since $\mathcal{N}\models\text{Th}(\mathcal{M})$, the cardinality of $\mathcal{M}$ is finite, and $N\supseteq M$, we have $N=M$. Therefore, $p(x)$ is realized in $\mathcal{M}$.
Remark: In some textbooks, a type $p(x)$ defined to be a set of formula such that for any finite subset $p_0(x)\subseteq p(x)$, $T\cup\{\exists x\bigwedge_{\varphi\in p_0(x)}\varphi(x)\}$ is consistent. Then the proof of the claim does not work, because $p(x)$ might not be realized in $\mathcal{M}$. In this case, for the proof of saturation of finite structures, for some $\varphi(x)$ with parameters $b\in M\backslash A$, one of $p(x)\cup\{\varphi(x)\}$ and $p(x)\cup\{\neg\varphi(x)\}$ must be consistent with $\text{Th}(\mathcal{M})$, so the type $p(x)$ can be extended to a complete type over $A\cup\{b\}$. Repeat this extension until the type is over $M$, we are again in the situation of the claim.
